# Can I get the Hidden Ability Wonder Skin on Venomoth in X&Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've caught over 20 Venomoths in the Friend's Safari, but none of them have Wonder Skin. [Serebii.net](http://serebii.net) says that Wonderskin is indeed available on XY. Am I doing this wrong? Are the chances very low?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wonder Skin is a Hidden Ability so it can only be found in the Safari of friends who have beaten the Elite Four (and been online at the same time as you at least once so your game downloads that information). After they have beaten the E4 a third pokemon comes into their safari and the Hidden Ability is reasonably abundant. Use a pokemon with Trace (like Gradevoir) to check abilities easier.

Comment: Ah.. I only have 2 of his pokemons unlocked... I guess that's why. Makes sense, thanks!